# json_encode on a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a problem using JSON and arrays.

Here is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ echo json_encode($row); }
```

The result is:

```
{"id":"1","title":"event1","start":"2009-11-10 14:18:15","end":"2009-11-03 14:38:22","allDay":"false","url":null}{"id":"2","title":"event2","start":"2009-11-09 15:41:20","end":"2009-11-10 16:41:25","allDay":"false","url":null}
```

But I want the result to look like this:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"event1","start":"2009-11-10 14:18:15","end":"2009-11-03 14:38:22","allDay":"false","url":null},{"id":"2","title":"event2","start":"2009-11-09 15:41:20","end":"2009-11-10 16:41:25","allDay":"false","url":null}]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myjsons = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $myjsons[] = json_encode(array($row)); 
}
print_r($myjsons);
```