# Failing conversion of string to int in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv, type-conversion

I am trying to get the input from a 2d php string array and convert the values in arr[i][1] (where i can be treated as a row and 1 as column in matrix) to integer as follows:

**JavaScript function:**

```js
var _input = <? php echo json_encode($output); ?> ; //2D String
var _sro = []; //string
var _src = []; //string
var _sru = []; //string

var aL = _input.length;
for (var i = 0; i < aL; i++) {
  _sro.push(_input[i][0]); //string
  _src.push(_input[i][1]); //string
  _sru.push(_input[i][2]); //string
}

alert(_src.toString()); //result = 1,1,2,9,6,1,24...
alert(typeof(_src).toString()); //res = string

var _lb = new Array(); //empty
var _dt = new Array(); //empty

for (var i = 0; i < aL; i++) {
  _dt.push(parseInt(_src[i])); //convert to int and push to arr
}

alert(_dt.toString()); //result = NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN.....
alert(typeof(_dt).toString()); //res = string

_lb = _sro;
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the end output for each value of **_dt is NaN** which means that it  does not get converted appropriately. To resolve this I have tried following:

1. using parseInt
2. using Number()
3. using the "+" operator
4. using both parseInt and Number()

For example:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < aL; i++) {
  _dt.push(Number(parseInt(_src[i]))); //convert to int and push to arr
}
```

and all these have failed. I am really lost and I have ran out of ideas after 2 days of googling and maybe someone in their wisdom will be able to help for which thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

**PHP Function:**

the below function generates the PHP array passed through to JS:

```js
//set error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

//set variables
$result = array();
$output = array();

//read in csv file
foreach(file("1OnScreen.csv") as $key => $str) {
  if ($key == 0)
    continue; // skip first line

  $values = str_getcsv($str, "\t", '', '');
  $result[] = $values;
}
$output = $result;
```

**CSV DATA**

The CSV File contains following data and the delimiter is \t:

```js
Owner Count Unassigned Other
AA1 1 0 1
AD 1 0 1
AR 2 0 2
BW 9 0 9
CM 6 0 6
CT 1 0 1
DB 24 0 24
EU 8 0 8
GM 5 0 5
GO 21 0 21
JF 1 0 1
JW 2 0 2
NH 10 0 10
RB 2 0 2
SPC 4 0 4
SP 2 0 2
TC 2 0 2
TG 1 0 1
VS 4 0 4
```

**JSON Output in JS**
Output of `_input` as I see it when running `alert(_input)` i think that the comma on the beginning of the new lines can be impacting the conversion and making it fail but I do not know how to go around that.

```js
AA1,1,0,1
,AD,1,0,1
,AR,2,0,2
,BW,9,0,9
,CM,6,0,6
,CT,1,0,1
,DB,24,0,24
,EU,8,0,8
,GM,5,0,5
,GO,21,0,21
,JF,1,0,1
,JW,2,0,2
,NH,10,0,10
,RB,2,0,2
,SPC,4,0,4
,SP,2,0,2
,TC,2,0,2
,TG,1,0,1
,VS,4,0,4
```

Comment: Are you sure `_src[i]` is a properly formatted string? Try `for (var i = 0; i < aL; i++) {
  _dt.push(parseInt(_src[i].toString()));
}`

Comment: Can you please provide the _input array as a javascript variable and not as a php inline script?

Comment: I also would try `for (var i = 0; i < aL; i++) { alert(_src[i].toString()); alert(typeof(_src[i]).toString()); _dt.push(parseInt(_src[i].toString())); }` to understand what's going on

Comment: @dirluca the alerts from the for loop are returning NaN as well. I have double checked the array being passed through and it seems as the array is not being parsed properly. I have included the same data using the     var _input = [["AA","1","0","1"],["AD","2","0","7"],["BW","5","0","9"]]; and it now works properly.

Comment: See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lp65je6/). It works. Are you sure this is the complete code you are using and you didn't post a snippet taking out the error?

Comment: @dirluca I am afraid that the problem is not associated with conversion but with the way that my 2d array is transposed through JSON (PHP) to my JS script and I am not sure how to tackle that. Cheers for your help :)

Comment: too little information on `$output` to help but try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667921/json-encode-on-a-two-dimensional-array) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914282/php-encode-json-2-dimensional-array)

Comment: @dirluca i have updated the question with the php code as well as the contents of the CSV which become the `$output` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion is failing because of certain special characters in the JSON string passed from the PHP script and "If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN." [W3C Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

In order to resolve the failing conversion or rather prevent it happening the use of regular expressions comes in handy (tutorial on regex available [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)) will lead to replacement of all characters apart from 1-9 (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555182/remove-all-special-characters-except-space-from-a-string-using-javascript)) such as: `/[^1-9 ]/g` when trying to convert the string into a number, so that the complete code looks like this:

```js
var _srOwner = <? php echo json_encode($sro_o); ?> ;
var _srCount = <? php echo json_encode($src_o); ?> ;
var _srUnassigned = <? php echo json_encode($sru_o); ?> ;

var _srC = [];
var _srU = [];


var aL = _srCount.length;
var cs = "";
var us = "";
var csi = "";
var usi = "";
var cn = 0;
var un = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < aL; i++) {
  cs = String(_srCount[i]); //string
  us = String(_srUnassigned[i]); //string
  csi = cs.replace(/[^1-9]/g, ""); //string
  usi = us.replace(/[^1-9]/g, ""); //string
  cn = parseInt(csi);
  un = Number(usi);
  _srC.push(cn);
  _srU.push(un);
};
```

where conversion using both `parseInt()` and `Number()` is successful and you may use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number) as guidance of which one to chose.

Special thanks for @dirluca for contribution to this question and great pointers.